# Hamburger Icon Not showing in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestRuntimepermission()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //for nav drawer
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,binding.root, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        binding.root.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        binding.shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, playerActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        binding.favouritButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, FavouriteActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        binding.playlistButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, PlayListActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }
    //for requesting permission
    private fun requestRuntimepermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),13)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),13)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode==13){
            if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                Toast.makeText(this,"permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),13)
        }


    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Hello, I wrote the codes, but the icon is not displayed
But when I move the screen to the right, the menu is displayed
i want display Hamburger Icon
please help me

Comment: I think you put a string but you need a drawable